# Infinispan JDBC String-Based cache store migration

Tags: infinispan

I have to do a store migration from infinispan v11 to infinispan v13.
I am following the instructions as mentioned in https://infinispan.org/docs/13.0.x/titles/upgrading/upgrading.html#migrating-data-between-stores

I am getting below exception. What am I doing wrong? Is store migration supported from version 11 to 13?

```
WARN: ISPN000554: jboss-marshalling is deprecated and planned for removal
Aug 25, 2022 9:29:35 PM org.infinispan.marshall.core.impl.DelegatingUserMarshaller start
INFO: ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.commons.marshall.ImmutableProtoStreamMarshaller'
Aug 25, 2022 9:29:35 PM org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry preStart
INFO: ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Triskaidekaphobia' 13.0.9.Final
Aug 25, 2022 9:29:36 PM org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.JbossMarshallingModule cacheManagerStarting
WARN: ISPN000554: jboss-marshalling is deprecated and planned for removal
Aug 25, 2022 9:29:36 PM org.infinispan.marshall.core.impl.DelegatingUserMarshaller start
INFO: ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.commons.marshall.ImmutableProtoStreamMarshaller'
Aug 25, 2022 9:29:36 PM org.jboss.threads.Version <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Threads version 2.3.3.Final
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:116)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:577)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.infinispan.persistence.spi.InitializationContext.getPersistenceMarshaller()" because "ctx" is null
    at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.impl.table.AbstractTableManager.<init> (AbstractTableManager.java:100)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.impl.table.AbstractTableManager.<init> (AbstractTableManager.java:86)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.impl.table.PostgresTableManager.<init> (PostgresTableManager.java:20)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.impl.table.TableManagerFactory.getManager (TableManagerFactory.java:49)
    at org.infinispan.tools.store.migrator.jdbc.JdbcStoreReader.getTableManager (JdbcStoreReader.java:80)
    at org.infinispan.tools.store.migrator.jdbc.JdbcStoreReader.iterator (JdbcStoreReader.java:68)
    at org.infinispan.tools.store.migrator.StoreMigrator.run (StoreMigrator.java:110)
    at org.infinispan.tools.store.migrator.StoreMigrator.main (StoreMigrator.java:138)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:577)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:833)
```

migrator.properties

```
source.type=JDBC_STRING
source.cache_name=mycache
source.version=11
source.dialect=POSTGRES
source.connection_pool.connection_url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5400/mydemo
source.connection_pool.driver_class=org.postgresql.Driver
source.connection_pool.username=mydemo
source.connection_pool.password=mypassword
source.table.string.table_name_prefix=my_cache
source.table.string.id.name=ID
source.table.string.id.type=VARCHAR
source.table.string.data.name=DATA
source.table.string.data.type=bytea
source.table.string.timestamp.name=TIMESTAMP
source.table.string.timestamp.type=BIGINT
source.table.string.segment.name=SEGMENT
source.table.string.segment.type=BIGINT
source.segment_count=256
source.db.major_version=14
source.db.minor_version=4

target.type=JDBC_STRING
target.version=13
target.cache_name=mycache
target.dialect=POSTGRES
target.connection_pool.connection_url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5430/minedemo
target.connection_pool.driver_class=org.postgresql.Driver
target.connection_pool.username=mydemo
target.connection_pool.password=mypassword
target.table.string.table_name_prefix=my_cache
target.table.string.id.name=ID
target.table.string.id.type=VARCHAR
target.table.string.data.name=DATA
target.table.string.data.type=bytea
target.table.string.timestamp.name=TIMESTAMP
target.table.string.timestamp.type=BIGINT
target.table.string.segment.name=SEGMENT
target.table.string.segment.type=BIGINT
target.segment_count=256
target.db.major_version=14
target.db.minor_version=5
target.key_to_string_mapper=org.infinispan.persistence.keymappers.DefaultTwoWayKey2StringMapper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a bug. I have created [ISPN-14108](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-14108) to track this and a fix should be available in the Infinispan 14.0.0.CR2 release.